# How does "for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);" work in c?

Tags: c, pointers, lowercase

I'm fairly new to programming and was just wondering by why this code:

```
for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
```

works to lower a string case in c, when p points to a string?

Comment: Hi. why did you think it should not work?\

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure about how *p can be used as the second parameter in the for loop, and how the loop knows to end

Comment: @Dave For a `'\0'` terminated string, `*p` evaluates to the `'\0'` for last character which breaks the loop and non zero for other characters which continues the loop.

Comment: The `for` terminates execution when reaches `*p==0`. Each C-String terminates with a 0 code!

Comment: Okay, cheers for the fast response guys! :)

Comment: Assuming that `p` is of type `char *`, the code above is equivalent to: `while (p[0] != '\0') { p[0] = tolower(p[0]); ++p; }`. Does it make more sense to you that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unpick, let's assume `p` is a pointer to a `char` and just before the `for` loop, it points to the first character in a string.

In C, strings are typically modelled by a set of contiguous `char` values with a final 0 added at the end which acts as the *null terminator*.

`*p` will evaluate to 0 once the string *null-terminator* is reached. Then the `for` loop will exit. (The second expression in the `for` loop acts as the termination test).

`++p` advances to the next character in the string.

`*p = tolower(*p)` sets that character to lower case.

Comment: Ah that's the bit i didn't know, so by default the condition of a for loop is if the second parameter is 0 then it will exit?

Comment: Indeed, the second expression in the `for` loop is the termination test.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this code:

```
for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
```

does *not*

> **”** works to lower a string case in c, when p points to a string?

It does work for pure ASCII, but since `char` usually is a signed type, and since `tolower` requires a non-negative argument (except the special value `EOF`), the piece will in general have Undefined Behavior.

To avoid that, cast the argument to `unsigned char`, like this:

```
for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = tolower( (unsigned char)*p );
```

Now it can work for single-byte encodings like Latin-1, provided you have set the correct locale via `setlocale`, e.g. `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );`. However, note that very common UTF-8 encoding is not a single byte per character. To deal with UTF-8 text you can convert it to a wide string and lowercase that.

---

Details:

- `*p` is an expression that denotes the object that `p` points to, presumably a `char`.
- As a continuation condition for the `for` loop, any non-zero `char` value that `*p` denotes, has the effect of logical True, while the zero `char` value at the end of the string has the effect of logical False, ending the loop.
- `++p` advances the pointer to point to the next `char`.

Comment: This is all a bit ahead of where I am but I'll try and sit down to understand it, cheers!

Comment: +1 for being picky (which is good, especially in C) and for mentioning encodings, just so the OP keeps in mind they're around.